# How do I set the a specific row or cell in a gridview (vb 2008)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, gridview

I know this will be easy, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.  How do you SET the current row in a gridview?  I find tons of ways to get data from it, but I what to set a current row or cell programatically.  I'm using VB 2008 express.  I also find lots of promising properties like Selected... but these are all read only and i can't set them.

Comment: I ended up selecting the leftmost cell of the desired row with  mainGrid.CurrentCell = mainGrid(0, selectedRow). This may be a way Microsoft supports their third party control vendors.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SelectedIndex property to set the current row.

Comment: For more info on the SelectedIndex Property go to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindex.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.  Let's say you have a need to select all the rows where we have more than 100 items in stock:

```
Private Sub btnSelectRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) Handles btnSelectRow.Click
    For Each r1 as DataGridViewRow in dataGridView1.Rows
        If r1.IsNewRow Then
            Exit For
        End If
        If Convert.ToInt32(r1.Cells(5).Value) > 100 Then
            r1.Selected = True
        End If
    Next        
End Sub
```

Here's the same thing in C#:

```
private void btnSelectRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow r1 in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (r1.IsNewRow) break;
        if ((int)r1.Cells[5].Value > 100)
        {
            r1.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you could use any criteria for selecting a row, but that gives you an idea.  Hope that helps.